# Как через Telethon переслать сообщение от отправителя в группу?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

У меня есть аккаунт в телеграмме, мне надо сделать чтобы если ему прислали сообщение в личное переписку, то он это сообщение перешлёт в группу, в моём коде он сообщение это отправляет но не видно от кого было это сообщение

```
async def handler(event: NewMessage.Event):
    phone = get_session_name(event.client)
    with DB() as db:
        autoresponder_message = db.get_autoresponder_text(phone)
    try:
        await event.reply(autoresponder_message)
        for chat in forward_to:
            print(chat)
        await client.send_message(chat, event.message)
        await event.client.forward_messages(forward_to, event.message)
    except Exception as e:
            logger.info(f"ошибка при автоответчике")
    logger.info(f"аккаунт {phone} получил сообщение в лс")
```

на скрине видно что если я написал сообщение на этот аккаунт, то он мне ответил и моё сообщение которое я ему написал он скидывает в группу которую я указал в своём коде, но он отправляет просто сообщение без пересылки от кого это сообщение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

должно быть вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]